# Is the button popover redundant display behavior a bug?

Tags: ngx-bootstrap

When I apply [this example](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/popover#triggers-custom) which display a button popover on hover (`mouseenter`) and hide it when not hovered (`mouseleave`), the popover display also when the button is clicked, and stay visible until the button is clicked a second time...

```
<button
  type="button"
  [popover]="popover"
  placement="bottom"
  triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"
  class="btn"
  [ngClass]="btnClass"
></button>
```

The code above show the popover under the button when hovered, but also on the top of the button when clicked...

Is this a normal behaviour ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ngx-bootrap button don't like when an input is named `popover`, so replacing this by the following code works:

```
<button
  type="button"
  [popover]="anyThingButPopoverNamedVar"
  placement="bottom"
  triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave"
  class="btn"
  [ngClass]="btnClass"
></button>
```